# Two videos on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have two videos on my page that are on top of each other. How do I move the second video to the center?
I have tried `<div>` tags with the `class="video"` attribute and the `text-align: center;` in css and nothing.
It remains the same when I go to preview my page and I do refresh every time.
I am getting frustrated because I can't seem to find a solution.
I just want to move the second video to the center. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your video in a container and give it a width less than page width and margin-left and margin-right auto, when container,  containing the video will be in center, the video will be in center automatically.

```
<div style="margin:0px auto;width:60%"><video></video></div>
```